# Shower panel walls with tile floor? NOT the kit pan/base

Tags: walls, shower, tile, sealing

I am planning to redo a small walk in shower. 60" x 32".

My plan is to rip out walls, replace with concrete backer, and redguard the entire thing. For the floor, it currently has small glass mosaic tiles. I want to remove this as well, sand down the old thinset and redguard the floor.

Does that make sense so far?

**For the remodel:**
I plan to order and install shower panels for the 3 sides. My question is, I want the pebble mosaic style floor and would apply this to the ground. Can I use the panels with a tile ground? How would you best seal the panel to the floor without the panel base kit.

I hope this makes sense, please let me know!

Comment: "* I want the pebble mosaic style floor and would apply this to the ground Can I use the panels with a tile ground?*" What?   If you want a tile floor then you you install tile on the floor. I do not understand your logic, can you  be more descriptive?

Comment: You do not need concrete backer board for a pre-made shower surround panels. Green board dry wall would be ok or, for overkill, you could use Denshield, it has a water proof membrane on it.  concrete backer board  is used for a strong sub-straight to install tile on. https://buildgp.com/product/densshield-tile-backer/

Comment: I have re-read, i think you are asking if you can use the surround panels on the walls but not use the pre-made pan, use the panels in conjunction with a tiled floor. Correct?

Comment: Correct. The current tiles are on drywall, so the walls are currently deteriorating pretty bad and I want to replace ALL of the walls behind since I know there is a ton of moisture. If I dont need to use concrete board, that is fine - but it is not overly expensive but green board sounds good as well. The wall panels I saw layer themselves over the "flange" portion of the base that is traditionally used with the kit. Since there will be NO flange portion - the panels will simply end at the floor, but without that 2-3inch overlap with the base. Does this make sense?

Comment: Generally those panels are held up and aligned with pins connecting to the shower tray. Not sure how stable it would be without the prefab pan and how you plan to transition the tile flooring to the walls. Generally the waterproof layer is behind the tile and on the sruface for the panels so there may be an issue with allowing water behind the panels without a good way for it to escape

Comment: I have never seen the pins you speak of. All the current ones I am seeing are the glued to the backer board (I plan to use a backer board coated with redguard for waterproofing) and a line of the adhesive on the bottom is pressed to the flange of the shower pan. I looked up DensShield and they have an instruction for floated walls that seems appropriate. Add DensShield to studs and allow a 1/4in (6mm) gap from floor. Fill gap with waterproof, flexible silicon sealant. Slope out the motar bed over the gap around corners. Does this seem good enough? PAge 10 of DensShield install guide.